# Solution to special system of linear equations $\mod (\mathbb{Z}/2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Say I have a system of linear equations of the form
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n 2 x_j k_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad i = 1,\ldots, m
$$
or equivalently
$$
2K\cdot\vec{x}\in \mathbb{Z}^n
$$
where $K$ is an integer matrix with orthogonal rows and columns, such that the GCD of every row and every column is 1, and $\vec{x}$ is a vector of real numbers.

**Question**: what are the constraints on $\vec{x}$?

I have the feeling that $\vec x$ should be a vector of half integers but can't prove nor disprove this claim.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $K=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)$ satisfies your conditions, but has the solution $(x_1,x_2)=(\tfrac14,\tfrac14)$.

Comment: Oh no, I forgot to add that the rows and columns were orthogonal as well. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: But then {{1,3},{3,1}} gives a system with the same solution.